# How to set highlight colors to default in neovim

Tags: lua, neovim

I want to make a toggler to enable and disable the background color. And I am doing something like this.

```
function M.flatter()
  vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "Normal", { bg = "none" })
  vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "NormalFloat", { bg = "none" })
end
```

but how would I make the background revert back to it's default color of the theme currently being used.

Answer (score 0):

To revert your background back, you could reload your colorscheme with `vim.cmd`:

```lua
function M.disable_bg()
  vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "Normal", { bg = "none" })
  vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "NormalFloat", { bg = "none" })
end

function M.enable_bg()
  vim.cmd([[colorscheme <YOUR COLORSCHEME>]])
end
```